# Refresh subtab in Service Cloud or page in classical view using Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, service-cloud-console, refresh, iteration

I've created a custom Visualforce page which is embedded into quick action (feed view). After user clicks submit button I'm changing the status of a case and trying to refresh the current subtab (service console) or the whole page (classic view).

Is there a way to do it together?

`window.location.href` works like charm with classical interface, in service console I've tried `sforce.interaction` methods - `refreshPage()` or `entityFeed.refreshObject('{!Case.id}, false, true, true)` - neither of them worked, the last one worked with refreshing case feed but I couldn't make it work with a tab.